# How to configure VACL in Cisco Packet Tracer?

Tags: cisco

I had a problem with my VACL configuration on cisco packet tracer.
My problem is I want to block ping to 192.168.6.2 from 192.168.1.0 but it keeps failing
Here is my code :
access-list 101 deny icmp 192.168.6.2 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 echo-reply
access-list 101 permit icmp any any
interface gig0/0/0 
ip access-group 101 in
ex
[my network picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta4b1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You swapped between source and destination adresses :
Access-list 101 deny icmp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 host 192.168.6.2 echo